# How to pass a parameter via `confirmDialog`?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I used to use javascript confirmation box, and would like to switch to PrimeFaces `<p:confirmDialog>`.

This is how it works now:

```
<p:commandLink id="deleteFGLinkId"
  action="#FilterPresetGroupMgmtBean.delete}"
  onclick="if( !confirm('Preset Group will be removed. Are you sure you want to continue?') ){return false;}"
  onstart="bui.show();"
  oncomplete="bui.hide();"
  update=":pmForm:filterPresetTable :pmForm:messagePanel">
    <f:param value="#{item.value.ID}" name="deleteID"></f:param>
    <h:graphicImage alt="Delete Image" style="border: none" value="./images/x.png"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

How would I pass a `deleteID` parameter in case I use `confirmDialog`? 
This doesn't work:

```
<p:commandLink onclick="confirmPGDeletePopup.show()">
  <f:param value="#{item.value.ID}" name="deleteID"></f:param>
  <h:graphicImage alt="Delete Image" style="border: none" value="./images/x.png"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

I also tried putting `<f:param>` into confirmation dialog OK button, but that didn't work too. Here is the dialog:

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confirmPGDeletePopup" 
                     header="Confirm delete"
                     message="Preset Group will be removed. Are you sure you want to continue?"  
                     severity="alert">         
      <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" oncomplete="confirmPGDeletePopup.hide()" action="#{PresetGroupMgmtBean.delete}" update=":pmForm:presetPanel :pmForm:messagePanel"/>
      <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" onclick="confirmPGDeletePopup.hide()" type="button" />                 
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass the parameter through the action method.

```
<p:commandLink value="Some Magic" 
    action="#{bean.setSelectedItemId(yourItemId)}"
    ajax="true"
        update="yourConfirmationDialog"
    oncomplete="yourConfirmationDialogWidget.show();"/>
```

Confirmation dialog:

```
<p:outputPanel id="yourConfirmationDialog" layout="block">
      <p:confirmDialog widgetVar="yourConfirmationDialogWidget" 
                 header="Confirm delete"
                 message="Are you sure you want delete the item with #{bean.selectedItemId} ?"  
                 severity="alert">         
         <p:commandButton id="confirm" value="Yes" oncomplete="yourConfirmationDialogWidget.hide()" action="#{bean.delete}" />
         <p:commandButton id="decline" value="No" onclick="yourConfirmationDialogWidget.hide()" type="button" />                 
     </p:confirmDialog>  
</p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Yes, but the `action` is now moved from `commandLink` down to `confirmDialog`. How would I pass the parameter down to dialog too?

Comment: you can update the confirmation dialog and retrieve the parameter from the bean. In the action method you deliver the parameter to the bean and get it after an update again from the bean in your confirmation dialog.